# Ist "exorbitant" heute noch gebräuchlich?

Tags: usage

Vor kurzem bin ich in einem Bericht über Lance Armstrong über das Wort "[exorbitant](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/exorbitant)" gestolpert, das man u. a. mit "außergewöhnlich" gleichsetzen kann. Ich habe dieses Wort nur früher gehört, heute nicht mehr.

Wird dieses Wort im deutschsprachigen Raum noch verwendet und wenn ja, wo?

Comment: Mein Gefühl sagt: ja, es wird noch verwendet. [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exorbitant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) scheint das zu stützen, ebenso wie eine [News Suche](https://www.google.de/#q=exorbitant&hl=de&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&psj=1&ei=Rr6FUPWoF8TetAaL24HoBA&ved=0CAoQ_AUoBA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4011f262eb544a19&bpcl=35466521&biw=1440&bih=731).

Comment: Man muss sowas immer in Relation sehen. [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exorbitant%2C+gewaltig%2C+au%C3%9Fergew%C3%B6hnlich%2C+%C3%BCbertrieben&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=). Daher erachte ich die Verwendung als äußerst gering. - In der gesprochenen Sprache ist der Begriff unter Garantie nochmals exorbitant seltener, als in der geschriebenen...

Comment: @Em1 Eigentor? Die Relation zeigt doch, dass exorbitant vor 200 Jahren viel ungebräuchlicher war als gewaltig und übertrieben und heute regelrecht boomt. (Ausgegangen davon, dass Ngram repräsentativ über alle Epochen ist.)

Comment: @musiKk Versteh ich nicht. *Exorbitant* ist bei mir die blaue Linie, die kontinuierlich an der 0%-Marke vorbeischrabbt. Da gibt es keinen "Boom". *Außergewöhnlich* hat sich vor 100 Jahren abgesetzt, *übertrieben* ist konstant geblieben und *gewaltig* ist nach zwei zwischenzeitlichen Hochs (1. und 2. Weltkrieg) auf dem absteigenden Ast.

Comment: Die Frage ist ja, ob Ngram so aussagekräftig ist - was für Bücher werden denn dort indiziert? Vermutlich weniger Fachbücher, oder? Das Wort *exorbitant* ist ja eines, das schon eher in der Fachliteratur oder "gehobenen Sprache" Verwendung findet. Da würde ich vermuten, dass eine News-Suche einen besseren Schnitt liefert.

Comment: Der Vergleich ist nicht ganz fair, da die Vergleichsworte als Adjektive oft verwendet werden. Exorbitant ist zwar technisch auch eins, aber wird hauptsächlich als Adverb gebraucht... daher hier eine 2-Wort-Phrase:

http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exorbitant+hoch%2Cau%C3%9Fergew%C3%B6hnlich+hoch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=

außergewöhnlich hoch liegt zwar vorne, aber exorbitant hoch ist definitiv nicht auf dem absteigenden Ast. Insofern, selten vielleicht, zeitgemäß sicherlich

Comment: Ich habe bewusst nicht geantwortet sondern kommentiert, da ich auch nicht einschätzen kann, wie aussagekräftig Ngram ist. Ich halte jedoch den Vergleich mit anderen Worten sowie die absolute Verwendung für irrelevant für die Frage. Schließlich geht es darum, ob sich die Verwendung _geändert_ hat - eine relative Größe.

Comment: @Em1 Einfach mal ausrechnen. 1800 ist *übertrieben* 200 mal häufiger als *exorbitant*. 2000 nur noch 17 mal. Absolut gesehen "schrabben" schrabben alle Werte kurz über der 0%-Marke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zum Beispiel

> exorbitant hohe Preise

Zumindest in Österreich mehr oder weniger gebräuchlich. Würde aber eher *übertrieben*, *übermäßig*, etc. als Synonyme anführen.

Comment: Ich kann dem nur zustimmen. "Exorbitant" ist zwar ein seltenes Wort, wird aber zumindest in Österreich gerne mal verwendet, und zwar am liebsten im Zusammenhang mit hohen Preisen (wie im Beispiel genannt). Laut Ngram hat sich die Popularität dieses Wortes vor allem zwischen 1985 und 1995 exorbitant gesteigert: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exorbitant&year_start=1950&year_end=2012&corpus=20

Comment: Ich höre und verwende *exorbitant* regelmäßig, allerdings eben vor allem in der Kollokation mit *teuer*, *hoch* oder *Gewinne*. Es ist sicherlich kein so vielseitiges Wort wie *sehr* oder *viel* (welches Wort ist das schon), aber es hat seinen festen Platz in der Sprache – und zwar unabhängig vom Register. Der Bäcker nebenan benutzt es genauso wie der Professor an der Uni oder der Philosoph im Fernsehen. (Ich lebe genau an der Grenze zwischen Rheinfränkisch und Moselfränkisch, also nochmal eine ganz andere Ecke als Österreich. Und der besagte Philosoph wird ohnehin bundesweit gesendet.)

Answer (score 10):

Ob "man" es heute noch verwendet, kann ich schwer sagen - es ist schwer, hier über die komplette deutschsprachige Allgemeinheit zu sprechen. Ich wohne in Hessen und sowohl einige Menschen aus meinem Bekanntenkreis als auch ich selbst verwenden das Wort durchaus. Gebürtig komme ich aus Nürnberg - auch dort habe ich es bereits gehört.

Ich glaube, dass man hier auch ein bisschen auf den Kontext schauen muss. Im "normalen" Sprachgebrauch wird man sicherlich nicht sagen *Die Pizza war exorbitant gut*, außer man möchte augenzwinkernd übertrieben darauf hinweisen, wie lecker sie war. Aber ich habe schon öfter Leute sagen hören *Das Essen dort ist exorbitant teuer*.

Vermutlich wird *exorbitant* jedoch häufiger im Kontext von schriftlichen oder gesprochenen Nachrichten (z. B. Tagesschau) oder Fachtexten Verwendung finden.

Comment: +1 für eine gute Zusammenfassung.

Comment: Ich kenne exorbitant nur im Sinne von "übertrieben", sprich mit eindeutig negativer Beimengung. In diesem Zusammenhang höre ich es jedoch regelmäßig.

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund weswegen man 'exorbitant' eher schreiben würde als sprechen, und die eher um Nüchternheit bemühte Tagesschau wie auch Fachtexte sollten sparsam mit Übertreibungen umgehen. Ich stimme zu, dass es eher in einen leicht affektierten Sprachgebrauch passt, und widerspreche @Ray heftig, insofern als eine Wertung mit dem Wort selbst nicht verbunden ist – auch der Restaurantbesitzer kann seinem Koch zuraunen, dass die Kartoffelsuppe an Petersiliensalz exorbitante Gewinne in die Kasse spült.

Comment: @userunknown Ich kenne das Wort gar nicht aus der gesprochenen (deutschen) Sprache. Hab's vllt hier und da mal aufgeschnappt, kann mich aber nicht mehr an einen konkreten Kontext erinnern.

Comment: Ich bleibe dabei, dass "exorbitant" und "angemessen" in meinem Umfeld nie synonym verwendet werden, sondern ersteres eher mit "unangemessen" oder "übertrieben" harmonisiert. Auch userunknown spricht im Zusammenhang mit "exorbitant" von einer "Übertreibung", mit der man sparsam umgehen solle. Letzteres Wort halte ich ebenfalls für wertend. Insofern verstehe ich seinen heftigen Widerspruch nicht. Aber da mag das subjektive Empfinden unterschiedlich ausfallen - und ich habe in meiner Anmerkung explizit auf das meinige Bezug genommen.

Comment: @Ray: Nein. Ich wollte auf den Widerspruch aufmerksam machen, dass Nachrichten angeblich den Begriff benutzen, der aber angeblich v.a. ironisch verwendet wird. Etwas, was übertrieben ... (teuer, heiß, ...) ist, das ist natürlich auch außergewöhnlich ... (teuer, heiß, ...). Aber der Umkehrschluß ist ein typischer Fehlschluß. Und ob man die Übetreibung, selbst wenn es eine ist, begrüßt oder nicht, das kommt doch sehr drauf an. Deswegen ist eine Bewertung als "negativ" m. E. auch unangemessen. Es kann negativ sein, aber muss nicht. "Ein exorbitanter Espresso" ist ein denkbares Lob.

Comment: @userunknown: Kommt ja darauf an, ob der Espresso exorbitant gut oder exorbitant schlecht war ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Nein, für die Frage, ob es ein denkbares Lob ist kommt es gerade nicht drauf an, wie ein spezieller Espresso war. In dem Du einräumst, er könne exorbitant gut gewesen sein hast Du schon bejaht, dass es `exorbitant` in anerkennender Form gibt.

Comment: @userunknown: "Exorbitant" an sich ist nicht "gut", "anerkennend" oder "abwertend". Es dient zur Steigerung einer qualitativen oder quantitativen Aussage. Du kannst gar nicht sagen, es ist ein "exorbitanter Expresso". Er kann "exorbitant gut" oder "exorbitant schlecht" sein, aber nicht nur "exorbitant". Das wäre, wie wenn man sagt, der "Expresso war ausgesprochen". Darauf wollte ich nur hinweisen mit meinem vorausgegangenen Kommentar.

Comment: Wenn man "exorbitant" als "außergewöhnlich" liest, dann kann man es sehr wohl sagen, und so sagt man auch. [Siehe diese Google-Suche](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=eine+exorbitante&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=R9XFUObtM8GUtAai-ID4Cw) - eine exorbitante Fehleinschätzung, eine exorbitante Intelligenzleistung usw. M.E. heißt "exorbitant" außerhalb des Orbits, also der Umlaufbahn - etwa des Mondes um die Erde oder der Erde um die Sonne. Außerhalb des gewohnten Bezugsystems, also.

Comment: Prima. Dann lassen wir das so. Und Deine Suche hat gleichzeitig auch die Frage beantwortet, ob das Wort überhaupt verwendet wird. Gut!

Answer (score 3):

Ich lebe in Hessen und habe lange in Baden-Württemberg gearbeitet. In beiden Bundesländern habe ich es vor allem im geschäftlichen Umfeld gehört und selbst verwendet. Reflektierend würde ich sagen, dass es meist dann verwendet wurde, wenn der Sprecher bei einer Steigerungsform seine gehobene Stellung mit zum Ausdruck bringen möchte. Das funktioniert m.E., weil "exorbitant" nicht so alltäglich und häufig verwendet wird wie andere Steigerungen, die dann eher formal (z.B. "außergewöhnlich") oder proletarisch (z.B. "super") klingen.

Ob positiv oder negativ spielt dabei keine Rolle - ein Mitarbeiter kann "exorbitant gute Arbeit" geleistet haben, und Geschäftszahlen können "exorbitant schlecht" sein.